# Vb.Net Exception Filtering CommunicationException vs ServiceModel.FaultException

Tags: .net, vb.net, exception

Ok, so I was trying to add some exception handling to a program and got some odd behavior.  I added the following Catch:

```
Catch ex As Exception When TypeOf ex Is IOException _
    OrElse TypeOf ex Is TimeoutException _
    OrElse TypeOf ex Is ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException _
    OrElse TypeOf ex Is ServiceModel.ServerTooBusyException _
    OrElse TypeOf ex Is ServiceModel.CommunicationException
```

And was surprised when the following exception fell into this block of code:

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: There was an exception running the extensions specified in the config file. ---> System.Web.HttpException: Maximum request length exceeded.
at System.Web.HttpRequest.GetEntireRawContent()
at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_InputStream()
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.Initialize()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.Initialize()
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)
Server stack trace:
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
```

When I debug this the condition TypeOf ex Is ServiceModel.CommunicationException is True, but I can't find that exception anywhere in the stacktrace or exception Message.  Can anybody explain this?  I'm trying to catch things like "The underlying connection was closed: ..." or "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`FaultException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.faultexception(v=vs.110).aspx) inherits from `CommunicationException`, and the [`TypeOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/typeof-operator) operator returns true if "objectexpression is of type typename or inherits from typename", so in this case it is correct that `TypeOf ex Is ServiceModel.CommunicationException`.